# How to Solve 0x80040154 (class not registered) error?

Tags: c#, class

I work with windows form application, which need some .dll file.

First time i finish it, build and run, it worked & is fine. 
(64 bit processor,64 bit Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012)

And then, i copy and paste entire project to other PC (64 bit processor, 32 bit Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012).
I couldn't run it, there is error message 
"Class not registered, exception form HResult 0x080040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)"

I have tried solutions :

1. change platform from anyCPU to x86, didn't work
2. Put all .dll file to system32 folder, didn't work
3. Tried to register class using regsvr32, but i got error message said that my .dll file :
   "was loaded but the entry point was not found"

And I can't even open my Form.cs[design] in Visual Studio,

Comment: You'll first need to install that ActiveX component you are using on that other machine.

Comment: How about this link > http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/run-wizard-error-0x80040154-class-not-registered/bb5df228-13fb-4c92-88f5-0acb9d0b6aec

Answer (score 1):

find out whether your dependent dll can work in win32.

it can be due to dll dependent on other which only available in 64.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the gflags [Show loader snaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Check this in gflags and attach windbg to your app, then you will see all detailed information about module loading. You will probably find some error similar as:

> LdrpGenericExceptionFilter - ERROR: Function LdrpSnapIAT raised exception 0xc0000139

Answer (score 0):

As Hans suggests, seems that you are using some ActiveX component. Try finding which dll is providing it then first register it by regsvr32.